# How many rows are equals between two matrices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, torch

I'm training a neural network for a multi-label classification problem. I have two rows A and B of size BxL (B = batch size, L = number of labels) where A are the actual labels of the minibatch and B are the predictions maded by my model, somethin like that:

```
A = array([[0., 1., 0.],
          [0., 1., 1.],
          [0., 1., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.]])

B = array([[1., 1., 0.],
          [0., 1., 1.],
          [0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 1., 0.]])
```

And I want to count how many samples are classified correctly (that means, how many rows are equals in A and B)

I would like to know if there is a way to do it with tensor/numpy parallel functions...

something like

```
sum(torch.eq(A,B, axis=0)) # that doesn't exists
```

Comment: Can you add the expected answer (one, I guess?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy` with `all`:

```
np.sum((A == B).all(1))
#1
```

This works by searching whether all values in each row match.

```
>>> A == B
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True]])
```

Gives you where the elements match, then `all(axis=1)` returns a boolean of rows where all values are `True`:

```
>>> (A == B).all(1)
array([False,  True, False, False])
```

Showing that the row at index `1` is an exact match between the two arrays.

Then, summing over the boolean array gives you the count of such rows.

Comment: That's is exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't thought of it, thank you so much,